# Filter divs based on text input

Tags: javascript, html, filterfunction

I'v got 2 layout for my filter div. 1 specific for desktop devices and 1 for mobile. I want it to filter items based on the text input the user gives. This is input div

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <input class="searchInput TextFilter-mobile" type="text" onkeyup="searchFunction()" placeholder="Zoeken..">
</div>
```

Now i got 2 separate divs that appear on the right device:
First the mobile one:

```
  <div class="card card-filterDiv zuivel special">
    <div class="card-horizontal">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
         <img class="clip-product-img-mobile" src="{% static 'main/images/img3.jpg' %}" alt="Card image cap">
         <button class="btn btn-success">
           <i class="fas fa-cart-plus add-to-cart-icon"></i>
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
       <h2 class="food card-title mr-0" style=">Bokkenpootjes</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the desktop one:

```
<div class="card card-filterDiv special zuivel">
  <img class="card-img-top clip-product-img-desktop" src="{% static 'main/images/img3.jpg' %}" alt="Card image cap">
    <button class="btn btn-success">
      <i class="fas fa-cart-plus add-to-cart-icon""></i>
    </button>
  <div class="card-body">
     <h2 class="food card-title mr-0">Bokkenpootjes</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have made a function which handles the logic:

```
function searchFunction() {
  // necessary variables
  var input, filter, card, h2, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.querySelector(".searchInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  cardfilter = document.getElementsByClassName('card-filterDiv');


  // Loop through all cards, and hide those who don't match the search query at h2 Tag
  for (i = 0; i < cardfilter.length; i++) {
    a = cardfilter[i].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      cardfilter[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      cardfilter[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

It works correctly on the mobile HTML but it is not on the desktop (second 1). I get no errors and everything seems to be OK. What am I missing?

Comment: did you console.log(cardfilter) to see if you indeed get those divs on desktop...

Comment: You got a double closing `"` in your `<i class="fas fa-cart-plus add-to-cart-icon""></i>`

Comment: @EugenSunic -> the variable is refering to the the class card-filterDiv which is the same on the desktop and on mobile.

Comment: @RickT When i put your code in a snippet it works perfectly even with the dubbel `"`. Please provide the needed code to reproduce your issue preferably in a SO code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. js can't handle two seperate input field on 1 function. Made a textinput for desktop as well as for mobile. My mistake!

Comment: but i see just one input field for both desktop and mobile...

Comment: Missed that one when I was copying to SO

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate your code.

In mobile one there is a style attribute on h2 without closing double-quotes.

On desktop one, you have added one more double-quote.

Otherwise, JS seems to work fine. :)

validated code:

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <input class="searchInput TextFilter-mobile" type="text" onkeyup="searchFunction()" placeholder="Zoeken..">
</div>

<div class="card card-filterDiv zuivel special">
  <div class="card-horizontal">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img class="clip-product-img-mobile" src="{% static 'main/images/img3.jpg' %}" alt="Card image cap" />
      <button class="btn btn-success">
        <i class="fas fa-cart-plus add-to-cart-icon"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="food card-title mr-0" style="">Bokkenpootjes</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="card card-filterDiv special zuivel">
  <img class="card-img-top clip-product-img-desktop" src="{% static 'main/images/img3.jpg' %}" alt="Card image cap">
    <button class="btn btn-success">
      <i class="fas fa-cart-plus add-to-cart-icon"></i>
    </button>
  <div class="card-body">
     <h2 class="food card-title mr-0">Bokkenpootjes</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was pure a mistake made when copying the code to over here. Got a few development styles placed inline currently. Tested this and it makes no difference for the text input filter on desktop.